# Adding event to Android default Calendar automatically

Tags: android, events, calendar

I'm trying to insert new event onto default calendar. So far I have tried two methods:

**1. Adding calendar event (but not showing on Default Calendar App)**

The code is using somekind like below

```
            ContentValues event = new ContentValues();
            event.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, calID);
            event.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, appointment.mTitle);
            event.put(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, appointment.mDescription);
            event.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_LOCATION, appointment.mAddress);

            event.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, appointment.mStartTime);
            event.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, appointment.mEndTime);
            event.put(CalendarContract.Events.ALL_DAY, 0);   // 0 for false, 1 for true
            event.put("eventStatus", 1); // 0 for tentative, 1 for confirmed, 2 for canceled
            event.put(CalendarContract.Events.HAS_ALARM, 1); // 0 for false, 1 for true
            event.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, TZone.getJavaTimeZoneId(appointment.mTZone)); 
Uri url = getContentResolver().insert(eventUri, event);
```

**2. Using Intent which open up the Calendar App**

Eventhough this open up the calendar app, but it didn't store automatically. the user requires to click save button to store it.

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT)
                    .setData(Events.CONTENT_URI)
                    .putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, appointment.getStartOfCompleteDateAndTimeOfEvent())
                    .putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME, appointment.getEndOfCompleteDateAndTimeOfEvent())
                    .putExtra(Events.TITLE, appointment.mTitle)
                    .putExtra(Events.DESCRIPTION, appointment.mDescription)
                    .putExtra(Events.EVENT_LOCATION, appointment.mAddress)
                   ;
            startActivity(intent);
```

What I actually want to do is to combine these two methods which to produce an automatically insert calendar event into the calendar app and if the calendar event open up, the event is already stored and can be viewed through the default calendar app.

If anyone knows, please help. Many thanks.

Comment: Have you set the permissions on your manifest file to write to Calendar? https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html#manifest

Comment: I did. the calendar event is actually stored, but i can't see it on calendar app.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void insertEntry(String pTitle, String pDescription, String pLocation, long pStartTimestamp, long pEndTimestamp) {
  ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
  ContentResolver mContentResolver = mContext.getContentResolver();
  values.put(Events.CALENDAR_ID, mCalendarID);
  values.put(Events.TITLE, pTitle);
  values.put(Events.DESCRIPTION, pDescription);
  values.put(Events.EVENT_LOCATION, pLocation);
  values.put(Events.DTSTART, pStartTimestamp);
  values.put(Events.DTEND, pEndTimestamp);
  values.put(Events.HAS_ALARM, 1); // 0 for false, 1 for true
  values.put(Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, TimeZone.getDefault().getDisplayName()); //get the Timezone
  Uri uri = mContentResolver.insert(Events.CONTENT_URI, values);
  Log.i(TAG,"calendar entry inserted");
}
```

This code works for me.

You have to make sure that your App has the permission to have read and write permission for the calendar. Simply add this to your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
```

Comment: I check on my calendar, but the event don't show up. I want the calendar app to be synced with my app, so whatever events stored by my app will be shown on the calendar app.

Comment: That's what I do in my app too.

Comment: in that case mine as well too. but thanks anyway for confirmation, appreciated. :)

Comment: @MF6265 mCalendarID is calenderView ID in ur App? I tried the same but nothing is added in my app calendar

Comment: @Ashok it's the id of the calendar into which the calendar entry is done. The code is really old by now, I'm not sure if it's still working as expected